# What's the time complexity of $\sum_{i=1}^k {N\choose i}$

Tags: time-complexity, upper-bound

I created an algorithm that is doing $\sum_{i=1}^k {n\choose i}$ inference calls to an ML model. Let's assume the inference calls are constant. Can I upper bound this without the binomial coefficient somehow? I would say its $\mathcal{O}\left(k {n\choose i}\right)$ but that's not a very intuitive expression. Is this expression NP-complete? It's been a while since I last did theoretical stuff, any hints are appreciated.

Comment: You may find the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n) helpful.

Answer (score 2):

$\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i}$ is not an algorithm nor a problem, therefore it does not make sense to ask about its time complexity or whether it is NP-complete.

That said, $\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i} = \Theta(2^n)$, which is probably what you were looking for. Indeed, $\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i} = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} - \binom{n}{0} = 2^n - 1$.

Comment: Yeah, maybe my formulation was imprecise. I was just looking for a bound. Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!